# tomcat not shutting down in CentOS

Tags: centos, tomcat

I was trying to shutdown tomcat but giving me following error.

`/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/catalina.sh: line 439: /usr/local/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory`

This is the full output,

`root@www [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin]# ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/catalina.sh: line 439: /usr/local/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Comment: So what's the actual question? It's been likely answered in the log you've provided.

Comment: I've flagged this question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

> /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/catalina.sh: line 439: /usr/local/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory

What's not to understand about that ? It looks like your `JRE_HOME` may be incorrect.